# Web API attribute routing 404?

Tags: c#, routes, attributes, asp.net-web-api2

My attribute routing in Web API project doesn't seem to work.
I try to access:

http://localhost/ControlTower2WebAPI/api/PurchaseOrder/Test/attribute/routing/why/

or

http://localhost/ControlTower2WebAPI/api/PurchaseOrder/Test/attribute/routing/why

I also tried F5 (debugging )in visual studio:

http://localhost:53915/api/PurchaseOrder/Test/attribute/routing/why
http://localhost:53915/api/PurchaseOrder/Test/attribute/routing/why/

Errors are the same:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //set API to return JSON
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

Code:

```
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("PurchaseOrder")]
public class PurchaseOrderController : ApiController
{
    private static ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    [System.Web.Http.Route("Test/attribute/routing/{_input}")]
    public JsonResult TestRoute(string _input)
    {
        try
        {
            JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
            jsonResult.Data = new
            {
                messageFromParameter = _input
            };
            return jsonResult;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error("TestRoute", exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant(?) Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="1000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: @JohnB yes, question edited.

Comment: so take the url in question and pop it in your browser - it will also say 404 most likely.  next work out if you have the correct url...

Comment: do you have other working endpoints?

Comment: try `http://localhost:53915/PurchaseOrder/Test/attribute/routing/why`, as that is all you have specified in your attribute routing

Comment: @fqhv your comment is the answer.